# Run specific test with every integration in TFS

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, automated-tests

How to make specific test cases run when changes are made to a specific component in TFS?
For example- I have 10 test cases for component A and 10 test cases for component B. When a developer merges a code reated to component A, I want only the test cases related to component A to run

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **Test Impact Analysis**. Described as this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff576128(v=vs.100).aspx),

> Test Impact Analysis (TIA) helps in analysis of impact of development on existing tests. Using TIA, developers know exactly which tests need to be verified as a result of their code change.

To enable test impact analysis in a build process, you need to:
1). Configure test impact analysis in a test settings file. Check the "Enabling Test Impact Collection" part of this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff576128(v=vs.100).aspx).

2). Specify to use the testsetting in the build definition.
3). Set **Analyze Test Impact**  to be true. Check the Enable Test Impact Analysis part of this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms253138(v=vs.110).aspx) for the details.

Additionally, it is possible for you customize your build process template to only run impacted tests: http://blog.robmaherconsulting.co.nz/2011/03/tfs-2010-build-only-run-impacted-tests.html